# AWS Lambda - transfer data from s3 to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 500GB data in s3 which I have to move to redshift and to do it automatically we are planning to use Lambda. But not sure if Lambda would be able to do that as it has time limit of 15 mins and as well size limit (I guess 10 gb). Could you please help us understand if Lambda can be use for transferring huge volume of data from s3 to redshift ?

Answer (score 1):

Your AWS Lambda function can issue the `COPY` command via the [`execute_statement()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift-data.html#RedshiftDataAPIService.Client.execute_statement) command.

This command will **continue operating without a connection**, so the Lambda function can end after sending the command. The Lambda timeout is unimportant unless you specifically want to wait until it has finished to check the status.

The Amazon Redshift [COPY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) command reads directly from an Amazon S3 bucket, so there is **no need to load the data into the Lambda function**.

I suggest that you first get the COPY command syntax correct by running it in the Redshift SQL console, and once it is working you could put the command in the Lambda function.